# Matlab: (1) Plotting multiple canvases, (2) holding them separately, (3) montage all

Tags: matlab, plot

*I've got* 10 grayscale images. I'd like to plot a simple YELLOW line over each image separately, then show them all over one plot (montage style).

*I tried* to draw all images first, but that made plotting lines very tricky (X,Y axes weren't standard for plotting over each separate image).

*I thought about* burning the line over the image, but I don't have the computer vision toolkit (easy functions to do this), otherwise it seemed complicated to both convert the grayscale to color and get it to burn the image.

I thought I might be able to use the function `newplot` to create a temporary plot space for each image, draw the line with a simple plot(...) call, then save it and just `montage(...)` all the individual plots at the end.

Is this possible? I've never played with the function `newplot` or tried to loop through individual plots, saving them up for a call to `montage(...)` this way, but it seems like a logical/simple approach.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing this.  Where do you want to draw this line in each image?  Can you show a pictorial example at all?  Also, you can use `line` to draw a line in a figure window.  You just need to be aware that the `y` axis is positive `y`-down when showing an image with `imshow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out with `subplot`, `subimage`, and `plot`, using subplot with the position arguments does what I want easily enough. Using subplot kept the axis relative to the subplot I was on so I could plot the line with a standard `fplot/plot` call.  The trick was normalizing the position to percentages vs. thinking of it in terms of pixels.

here's some code demoing it:

```
      % Loop through this code, each time moving the subplot by position
      LOOP {
        % calculate left & bottom position as percentages (0..1)
        subplot( 'Position', [ left bottom (1/cols) (1/rows) ] );
        hold on

        % (1) Draw the image
        subimage(tmpImg, [0 255]);
        axis off;

        % (2) Plot the line over the original image
        F = @(x) polyval(p, x);
        fplot(F, [1 dimX 1 dimY], '-y');
      }
```

Comment: Nice! Can you accept your answer so the thread is closed? Thanks!